# How does the randomness in the weight initialization affect a neural network's training result?

Tags: neural-network

In general, is it worth training a network for many sets of random initial weights and pick the best result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for two reasons:

a)  many different sets (say several hundred) will give you a better chance at finding an optimum solution if one exists; and

b)  even if you don't find an optimum, the repeated runs will give you a better understanding of the solution space (the nature of the problem) and a validation (or invalidation) of your approach.

Running an experiment with one or only a handful of different initial weight sets really doesn't say anything about the reproducibility of your results.